# Swapping two elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing mooc.fi, my code works but it won't submit.

errors I'm getting

---

the method swap does not work correctly with parameter 4, 7, 8, 6 index1=0 index2=3

the result was 4, 7, 8, 6 but it should have been 6, 7, 8, 4

---

and

---

the method sort does not work correctly with parameter 10, 20, 6, -1, 13, 11

the result was 10, 20, 6, -1, 13, 11 but it should have been -1, 6, 10, 11, 13, 20

---

I know the errors are connected but I'm not too sure what to do to fix this, any help is appreciated! thank you!

My Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int smallest(int[] array) {
        int start = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < start) {
                start = array[i];
            }
        }
        return start;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallest(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == smallest(array)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static int indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(int[] array, int index) {
        int minIndex = index;
        for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }

    public static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
        int hold = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            hold = array[index1];
            array[index1] = array[index2];
            array[index2] = hold;
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            swap(array, i, indexOfTheSmallestStartingFrom(array, i));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4};
        sort(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask on the MOOC forums or chat: http://mooc.fi/courses/2013/programming-part-1/#help-with-the-exercises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm is designed very badly. both smallest and indexOfSmallest use a loop, this will degrade geometrically.

The swap should not be scanning the entire array as you only want to swap two elements, *not all of them!*

You're effectively doing a whack version of a bubble-sort, but in a really convoluted way with too many loops. This will start to perform horribly with any decent sized list.

A much simpler version can be found [here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm)

Comment: I can see how this way can be inefficient but to pass the exercise I think I had to do it this way.

Comment: @syntax: Your `swap()` method has a useless (and potentially harmful) `for` loop around the code. Remove it, and at least your first error should go away. (Bonus exercise: Figure out in which cases your original code will work despite the needless loop, and in which cases it will fail.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop for the swap method. As you only want to change the two element once and not n-times (which results in not swapping them at all if n is an even number).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] swapArrayElement(int arr[], int a, int b) {
        int index1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == a || arr[i] == b) {
                index1 = i;
                if (arr[i] == a) {
                    for (int k = index1; k < arr.length; k++) {
                        if (arr[k] == b) {
                            arr[k] = arr[index1];
                            arr[index1] = b;
                        }
                    }
                    return arr;
                } else if (arr[i] == b) {
                    {
                        for (int k = index1; k < arr.length; k++) {
                            if (arr[k] == a) {
                                arr[k] = arr[index1];
                                arr[index1] = a;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return arr;
                }

            }

        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is just a dump of code and does not help the OP to understand their mistakes *or* how to do it better. Instead of dumping code, you should always *explain* why and how stuff works.